# Angular component not updated when service updates

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

I have an Angular 2 app with an `events` service which has a `delete` method:

```
let EVENTS: TimelineEvent[] = [
    {
      event: 'foo',
      timestamp: 1512205360,
    },
    {
      event: 'bar',
      timestamp: 1511208360,
    }
  ];

@Injectable()
export class EventsService {

  getEvents(): Promise<TimelineEvent[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(EVENTS);
  }

  deleteEvent(deletedEvent) {
    EVENTS = EVENTS.filter((event) => event.timestamp != deletedEvent.timestamp);
  }
}
```

My main component displays these events, and uses an `onClick` handler to call the service's `deleteEvent` method:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [EventsService],
  template: `
    <div>
      <event *ngFor="let timelineEvent of events" [timelineEvent]="timelineEvent" [deleteEvent]="deleteEvent"></event>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  constructor(private eventsService: EventsService) {

  }
  events

  getEvents(): void {
    this.eventsService.getEvents().then(events => this.events = events);
  }

  deleteEvent(event): void {
    this.eventsService.deleteEvent(event); 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEvents();
  }
}
```

I can see by `console.logging` the `EVENTS` array that this is correctly updated. But the display is not updated. Where am I going wrong?

Example code here: [https://plnkr.co/edit/cENnHeHORnDT50RaTyoI](https://plnkr.co/edit/cENnHeHORnDT50RaTyoI?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove the event in your service, not in your component. The list of event in your component remains unupdated.

A way to solve it:

1 - Make the deleteEvent method of your service returning promise:

```
deleteEvent(deletedEvent) {
    EVENTS = EVENTS.filter((event) => event.timestamp !== deletedEvent.timestamp);
    return Promise.resolve("Successfully deleted");
}
```

2 - And in your component, reload events on the success of the deleting action:

```
deleteEvent = (event) => {
    this.eventsService.deleteEvent(event).then(res => this.getEvents()); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added `this.getEvents()` to my component's `delete` method but now it returns the error `this.getEvents is not a function`. I've updated the Plunker code.

Comment: Updated Plunker - I still get `TypeError: _this.getEvents is not a function`.

Comment: Working! Why does the arrow function format work? Just curious.

Comment: By using arrow function, the context of 'this' doesn't change (when working with callbacks, ... ).